# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty - user sign up form - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a basic login/sign up form in Rails 4 and I keep getting the error "first argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" for @user.
The part it doesn't like is this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

but I have the 'new' method in my controller, which is the problem most people seem to have who ask about this error:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
```

can anyone please help?

addendum: changing it to `<%= form_for User.new do` doesn't work either...

Comment: when is the error coming, when rendering the form or when posting it? Can you gist the entire error?

Comment: Full error message together with backtrace, please :)

Comment: sevenseacat - the error happens for both.  I'm afraid I'm not sure what backtrace is but app/views/home/index.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb__2797544976222396038_2158013460' ???

Comment: Your error is coming from your `index` view, not your `new` view.  What file is the form in?

Comment: I was trying to render it on my index view, it works fine on my new view.  Am I being incredibly stupid?  The form is in views/users.

Comment: Although it's in your index view `<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>` should work. So might be issue is that Your form is not rendering in your index view. It may be calling any other view partial. So try add debugger on your form and see debugger stuck or not

Comment: I'm not getting anything from debugger at all O.o I must be using it wrongly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is looking for an instance of a class, in this case User in order to do something with it (i.e. create a new one or edit an existing one).  In order for you allow users to register on your index page (which I wouldn't recommend - that breaks RESTful design) you would need to also have this in your `UsersController`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @user = User.new
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip re RESTful design, I'll do something else on here.  Thank you!